# when i run my testcafe script it shows "ERROR The "html" reporter does not exist. "

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

i got this error "ERROR The "html" reporter does not exist. " when i run my testcafe scripts
my code:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';


fixture`Example `
    .page`google.com`;


test('google search', async t => {
    await t

});
```

and i import `testcafe-reporter-html`
but still i got this error:

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

TestCafe does not include the `testcafe-reporter-html` by default, so you need to install it. Run the following command in the directory of your project:

```
npm install testcafe-reporter-html
```

Note that you do not need to import the reporter. Testcafe will find it automatically.